# How to migrate Nexus repository from 1.7 to 3.x?

Tags: repository, nexus, migrate

Hello I want to migrate Nexus repository from 1.7 to 3.x, Is there any way to do ?

Answer (score 0):

First upgrade to version 2.7.2, then upgrade to the latest Nexus Repo 2.x version.

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM2/Upgrading

Then you can do a migration to Nexus Repo 3:

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Upgrading+from+Nexus+Repository+Manager+2